# MySQL/InnoDB - order of PK in Leaf Node

Tags: mysql, indexing, innodb

I'm using InnoDB.

If I have data being like

```
[PKID : ?] col1
---------------
[PKID : 1] 7
[PKID : 2] 7
[PKID : 3] 5
[PKID : 4] 5
[PKID : 5] 7
```

and has B+Tree index of col1. It would be like this:

```
5(PKID : 3 or 4) - 5(PKID : 3 or 4) - 7 (PKID : 1 or 2 or 5) - 7 (PKID : 1 or 2 or 5) - 7 (PKID : 1 or 2 or 5)
```

I want to know that clustered index is always ordered by PKID like this or not:

```
5(PKID : 3) - 5(PKID : 4) - 7 (PKID : 1) - 7 (PKID : 2) - 7 (PKID : 5)
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In principle, InnoDB doesn't need PK sorted in the secondary index. For each record in the secondary index it calls `Handler_read_rnd` to get fields from PRIMARY index.

But for optimal reads it might sort it.

It should be possible to check this. After a SELECT that reads from the secondary index check if `Handler_read_rnd_next` even increases. If so, then PK values are sorted too.

Comment: Another way would be to dump records from the secondary index an check what the actual order is.